# Merge Cells of one specific column if equal value

Tags: excel, vba, loops, merge

I need to loop over all rows (except my header rows) and merge all cells with the same value in the same column. Before I do this I already made sure, that the column is sorted.
So I have some setup like this.

```
a b c d e
1 x x x x 
2 x x x x
2 x x x x
2 x x x x
3 x x x x
3 x x x x
```

And need this

```
a b c d e
1 x x x x 
2 x x x x
  x x x x
  x x x x
3 x x x x
  x x x x
```

With my code I achieved to merge two equal cells. Instead I need to merge all equal cells.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i - 1, 1)).Merge
        End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: It is important, that the code merges ONLY the cells of the specific column, and not all columns of the sheet.

Comment: This should do the trick...
`Sub MergeColumnA()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = myLastRow - 1 To 6 Step -1
        If Cells(i + 1, 1) <> "" Then
            If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i + 1, 1) Then Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Merge
        End If
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

This method does not use merged cells, but achieves the same visual effect:

Say we start with:

[image]

Running this macro:

```
Sub HideDups()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 3 Step -1
        With Cells(i, 1)
            If .Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
                .Font.ColorIndex = 2
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this result:

[image]

**NOTE:**

No cells are merged.  This visual effect is the same because consecutive duplicates in the same column are "hidden" by having the colour of the font be the same as the colour of the cell background.

Comment: Nice Approach. I appreciate. Makes sense, since merged cells loose some kind of information and create lots of trouble for formatting.

Comment: @gco I use this method when I have to make a report that "looks like" a Pivot Table.

Comment: thats awesome and I will definitely use it in the future. anyway, my co-worker needs merged cells (see my comment in my question for the solution).

Comment: @gco  I would, at least, discuss the alternative with your co-worker.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I needed something similar. Here's what I came up with.

```
Sub MergeLikeCells()

    Dim varTestVal As Variant
    Dim intRowCount As Integer
    Dim intAdjustment As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    'Find like values in column A - Merge and Center Cells
    While Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value <> ""
     'If instead you have blanks in the column, change the prev statement to While Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value <> "." and add "." to the last 2 rows of the data
        intRowCount = 1
        varTestVal = Selection.Value
        While Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value = varTestVal
            intRowCount = intRowCount + 1
            Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Selection.ClearContents
        Wend
        intAdjustment = (intRowCount * -1) + 1
        Selection.Offset(intAdjustment, 0).Select
        Selection.Resize(intRowCount, 1).Select
        With Selection
            .Merge
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 1).Select
    Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution as below, have a good day!

```
Sub MergeSameValue()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    StartRow = 2
    LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim StartMerge As Integer
    StartMerge = StartRow
    
    For i = StartRow + 1 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If Cells(i, 1) <> Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
                Range(Cells(i - 1, 1), Cells(StartMerge, 1)).Merge
                StartMerge = i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```